# Error Bars appearing too low in ggplot2 bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Been scouring the site (and others) for a solution to the problem pictured below. I can't get the error bars to move from their 'low' position, despite trying lots of different solutions to similar problems I have encountered here and elsewhere.

[image]

The problem occurs whether I produce one graph alone or the two and combine them with `gridExtra`.

Here is the code and a sample of each dataset included:

First dataset example:

```
Group      PSQI Time_Point
1 Control    2   Baseline
2 Control    2   Baseline
3 Control    2   Baseline
4 Control   13   Baseline
5 Control    1   Baseline
6 Control    7   Baseline
```

Second:

```
  Group    ESS Time_Point
1 Control   3   Baseline
2 Control   4   Baseline
3 Control   1   Baseline
4 Control   0   Baseline
5 Control   7   Baseline
6 Control  11   Baseline
```

Code:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

p1 <- ggplot(PSQI_Graph,aes(fill=Group,y=PSQI,x=Time_Point)) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", width = 0.50) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = 
position_dodge(.5), width = .25)+
    guides(fill = F)+
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Mean PSQI Score", limits=c(0,25))+
    xlab("Time Point") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1.5, keyheight = 1))+
    theme_bw()
```

Would really like to get this data out, so would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and provide a [reproducible example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex) that showcases your problem and that is ready to copy-paste-run in a new R session.

Comment: If you calculate mean for both levels in each facet, you'll notice that the center of the error bars is right where mean is.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use `geom_errorbar`. First, you'll have to make a new `data.frame` with one line per bar, including the standard error (I added an "After" timepoint to show how this looks):

```
    Group PSQI Time_Point StdErr
1 Control 4.50   Baseline   1.91
2 Control 7.17      After   0.79
```

Then, this `ggplot` call will work:

```
ggplot(psqi, aes(fill=Group, y=PSQI, x=Time_Point, ymin=PSQI-StdErr, ymax=PSQI+StdErr)) + #the ymin and ymax parameters here tell it where to put the top and bottom error bars
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    geom_errorbar() #you can change the width and thickness of the bars
```

Yielding this image:

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly! Legend!